# notification hub using azure function

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub, azure-functions

How do I send notification using hub from azure functions:

```
context.bindings.notification = {
   message: "Hello from " + req.body.name
};
```

Getting an error.

The document written:

```
This example sends a notification for a template registration that contains
```

How can I register template when using azure function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, here's a link to the [notification hub bindings docs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-templates/blob/dev/Documentation/notificationHubOut.md)

Here is what you need to do:

1. From a mobile client app, [register a template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-ios-apple-push-notification-apns-get-started)

   - i.e. `{"aps": {"alert": "$(message)"}}`
2. Send the template payload from the azure function.  You should receive the push on devices which have registered with the template

   - i.e. `context.bindings.notification = {
     message: "this goes in the $(message) above"
     };`

Comment: How about sending Windows 10 app that require toast XML template?

Comment: You can send WNS notifications by setting the platform to WNS. See [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/80715077-30de-4eca-8887-088f6bab670d/azure-function-and-notification-hub?forum=AzureFunctions) for sample code